# Object method is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**TL;DR** What's wrong with `for (car in carList) {...}` where `carList` is an array?

I have a class `Car` with a method `reset()`. On instantiation, a `Car` object adds itself to a list of cars. I want to use a method, `reset()` in a for loop. Here is my (cut down) code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var carList = [];

    function Car(speed) {
        carList.push($(this));
        console.log(carList);
        ...
        this.reset = function() {
            // Does some resetting stuff
        };
    }

    car1 = new Car(0.4);
    car2 = new Car(0.1);

    for (car in carList) {
        car.reset();
    }
});
```

This produces an `Uncaught TypeError`. The console log is

```
> [m.fn.init[1]]
> [m.fn.init[1], m.fn.init[1]]
> Uncaught TypeError: car.reset is not a function
```

But if I type `car1.reset()` in the console, it works. Why is this?

Comment: You probably also should define the variable, `for ( var car in carList ) {`

Comment: I would be very reluctant to have the reference to `carList` in the constructor as it sets up a specific dependancy for the constructor. IMO it would be better to do this: `carList.push(new Car(0.4));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is done wrong. It should be:

```
for (var i in carList) {
    carList[i].reset();
}
```

or, if you are using ES6:

```
for (var car of carList) {
    car.reset();
}
```

See documentation for [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Also, when you push an instance of `Car`, you should use `this` instead of `$(this)`, as @JamesMcLaughlin pointed.

Comment: Note: the latter method using ES6 is not supported by IE11 https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @BinaryFunt For ES6 compatibility check [kangax's compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Answer (score 2):

```
function Car(speed) {
    carList.push($(this));
```

You're jQuery-ifying the Car object for some reason, but it's not a DOM element so it doesn't make any sense.

Change it to:

```
function Car(speed) {
    carList.push(this);
```

Comment: I tried the non-jQuery-ified `push(this)` but this in itself only changes `[m.fn.init[1], m.fn.init[1]]` to `> [Car, Car]`. The error still happens unless I change my `for` syntax as Gothdo answered. But it is still necessary to use the non-jQuery-ified version, so thank you